# Can a Pointer variable holds the address of another Pointer Variable?

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Is it possible to make a pointer variable hold the address of another pointer variable? eg:
`int a; 
    int *ptr,*ptr1; 
    ptr=&a; 
    ptr1=&ptr;`

Comment: What does `int **ptr` mean?

Comment: A pointer holds an address.  So long as it's typed correctly (or you fake it somehow), the pointer doesn't "care" what's being addressed. But note that you should type the pointer as addressing a pointer, not an int or whatever.

Comment: @HotLicks: this is true in common implementations, but not in principle and not in the formal language. There's no guarantee you can cast pointers through incorrect pointer types and back and get the same value back, and in fact on machines with certain alignment considerations and such, you might not. You really do need the right pointer type, or you could use a character-type pointer or `void` pointer which can safely hold any pointer.

Comment: I kinda view pointers like envelopes in the amazing race. When you find an envelope you need to open it to find the next location and hopefully that's your goal. Your scenario is like opening an envelope that leads to an envelope to the final destination, which is perfectly legitimite.

Comment: @R.. -- Yeah, I was aware of all that, but didn't want to write a book.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Sure, a pointer to a pointer.

```
int i;
int *pi = &i;
int **ppi = &pi;
```

There is nothing particularly unusual about a pointer to a pointer. It's a variable like any other, and it contains the address of a variable like any other. It's just a matter of setting the correct type so that the compiler knows what to do with them.

Comment: `ptr` and `ptr` have the same name in your example, and thus there's a type mismatch (`int **` vs `int ***`) making the code invalid C.

Comment: So they do. That's what I get for coding without a compiler. Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it needs to have the right type. In your example `int *ptr,*ptr1;` both `ptr` and `ptr1` have type "pointer to `int`", which can only point to an `int`, not a pointer. If you declare `int *ptr, **ptr1;`, then `ptr1` has type "pointer to `int *`" and thus can point to `ptr`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a sample showing what happens

```
int a = 13; 
int *ptr,
int **ptr1;       // ** means pointer to pointer
ptr = &a;   
ptr1 = &ptr;

cout << a;        //value of a  

cout << *ptr;     //ptr points to a, *ptr is value of a  
cout << **ptr1;   //same as above

cout << &ptr;     //prints out the address of ptr
cout << *ptr1;    //same as above
```

It works the same for `int ***ptr`, `int ****ptr`.

Answer (score 0):

Pointer to pointer is possible (and very common), but `int*` may not be large enough to contain the address of another `int*`. use `int**`. (or `void*`, for generally pointer)

Answer (score 0):

There's two answers here and they're both yes.

Two pointers can point to the same location

```
int b, *p1=&b, *p2=&b;
*p1 = 123;
*p2; // equals 123
```

You can also have a pointer to a pointer:

int x=2, y=3, *p=&x, **q=&p;

Note the extra asterisk.

```
**q; // equals 2
*q = &y;
**q; // equals 3
**q = 4;
  y; // equals 4
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, 
Pls see the following code. I hope it will serve your purpose

```
int a = 4;
int *ptr = &a;
int *ptr1 = (int*)&ptr; 
cout << **(int**)ptr1;
```

Here ptr1 is single pointer but behaves as double pointer